# How to copy specific artifacts across multiple instances in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

How can I copy a specific artifact to another instance of Artifactory?

From what I can see the export/import functionality only works for full system or full single repo copying. I don't want to replicate the full repo either. I just want to copy specific artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the JFrog CLI? It can be used to download artifacts from Artifactory by giving a specific pattern. So, for example, you can download only the "war" files from a specific repository and then import it / deploy it to the rest of the instances that you want. You can also write a script using the JFrog CLI that will download and then publish those artifacts to the other Artifactory instances using the CLI.

https://www.jfrog.com/getcli/

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean download an artifact to my machine then publish it to the other instance. I was wondering if there was a way to directly copy directly between instances.

Comment: Other then replication there is no out of the box option to do what you want.

The only option would be to write a user plugin which requires a PRO version of Artifactory and some time to write it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CLI for Jfrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) for copying the file with the new name to another repo:

```
    jfrog rt cp "your-artifactory-repo/artifact.extension" your-new-artifactory-repo/artifact.extension
```

Note: you can use * if you want to copy all the artifacts from the folder.

Comment: this does not seem to work between artifactory instances. With basic auth I get some strange errors